# Is this the correct way to interpret $M[G]\models\psi$

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

In Kunen's Set Theory, in the context of forcing, $M[G]$ is the set of all $\mathbb{P}$-names in $M$ evaluated with respect to $G$. We then go on to define the forcing language and restrict it to the $\mathbb{P}$-names in $M$. Then we wish to define when a sentence holds in $M[G]$. This is where Kunen says the following:

Let $\psi$ be a sentence of $\mathfrak{FL} _\mathbb{P}\cap M$. Then $M[G] \models \psi$ has its usual model-theoretic meaning from Definition 1.15.5, interpreting $\in$ as membership, and interpreting each name $\tau$ as $\tau_G$.

Now the definition he is referring to here is very general. In particular, we have a closed formula so we do not care about the assignment of the free variables (since there are none) and we have a concrete way of evaluating the constant terms.

Here is what I believe this translates to in our case:
Let $\psi$ be a sentence of $\mathfrak{FL} _\mathbb{P}\cap M$. Then $M[G] \models \psi$ is defined recursively over the complexity of $\psi$ as follows:
$$(1)\text{ }M[G] \models (\tau^1=\tau^2) \text{ iff } \tau^1_G=\tau^2_G \text{ where } \tau^1,\tau^2 \text{ are } \mathbb{P}\text{-names in M}$$
$$(2)\text{ }M[G] \models (\tau^1\in\tau^2) \text{ iff } \tau^1_G\in\tau^2_G \text{ where } \tau^1,\tau^2 \text{ are } \mathbb{P}\text{-names in M}$$
$$(3)\text{ }M[G] \models (\neg\phi) \text{ iff } M[G] \not\models (\phi)$$
$$(4)\text{ }M[G] \models (\phi_1\wedge\phi_2) \text{ iff } M[G] \models \phi_1 \text{ and } M[G] \models \phi_2$$
$$(5)\text{ }M[G] \models (\exists x \phi(x)) \text{ iff there is some } a\in M \text{ s.t. }  M[G] \models \phi(a)$$

**Comments and concerns:**

Points (1) and (2) only consider the constants of the alphabet, i.e. $\mathbb{P}$-names in this case. In general, one would have "terms" there, so variables, constants or functions of terms. However, we don't have any functions in our language, and if one of the terms is a variable, then $\psi$ would no longer be a closed formula.

My confusion/doubt stems from number (5), I am not sure if it is correct, in particular, is $a$ supposed to be in $M,M[G]$ or $M^\mathbb{P}$(i.e. $\mathbb{P}$-names in $M$).

Any hints and or ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the "usual model theoretical meaning", so $M[G]\models \exists x \varphi(x)$ means there is some $a\in M[G]$ such that $M[G]\models \varphi(a).$ This is equivalent to there being a $\sigma\in M^{\mathbb P}$ such that $M[G]\models \varphi(\dot \sigma)$ (where $\dot \sigma$ is the constant symbol corresponding to $\sigma$), but not to there being an $a\in M$ such that $M[G]\models \varphi(a).$

Comment: True! Makes perfect sense now that you say it! Thank you very much for the help!